# Turn file uploads on for php on Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I can't get the php.ini setting for file uploads to turn on. The default setting is off as described [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_Directives_with_new_initialization_defaults). In the documentation it says you can add your own php.ini file and change the default settings. My php.ini file is below and the other settings are working and show when calling phpinfo.

```
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "php_sapi_name, gc_enabled, phpinfo"
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_file_uploads = 20
file_uploads = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you aware that Google App Engine only allows upload of files via specific API instead of using the language's default upload?

The current solution for handling file upload in PHP is described here:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/

Comment: yup you need to use createUploadUrl to upload to Google Cloud Storage ... this should be the only change you need.

Comment: If file uploads are off how is $_FILES going to be populated with data to be used by cloud storage? I'm not trying to upload that needs to be persistent.

I need up upload a file, parse it and thats it, it can be removed right after the action.

Comment: User it like you normally would. Just fopen the tmp_file.

Comment: How can you use $_FILES if its not populated? The array is empty because file uploads are disabled. It appears they cannot be enabled via a custom php.ini

Comment: ok even for reading just the basic information on the upload you have to use createUploadUrl. $_FILES is then populated on the upload handler script.