# Google App Engine, PHP: $_FILES array empty - tried everything others have suggested here

Tags: php, file, google-app-engine, post

This is my 1st post.  I have read several posts on this issue. None so far has solved my very basic problem.  I must be missing something about php.ini, or app.yaml, or maybe I *really do* have to create a 'bucket' in Google Cloud Storage just to select a file on one page and pass it to another?  I am stuck.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Calling Form, 'import.php':

```
<form action="import_action.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
    <tr><td><input type="file" name="import_file" size="2000000"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" name="import" value="Import File"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

... a file is selected.  'Import File' button is pressed.

Form invoked by POST, 'import_action.php':

```
<html>
  <head>Import Action</head>
  <table>
    <tr><td>$_POST: <? var_dump($_POST); ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>$_FILES: <? var_dump($_FILES); ?></td></tr>
  </table>
</html>
```

Output, 'import_action.php':

Import Action
$_POST: array(1) { ["import"]=> string(11) "Import File" }
$_FILES: array(0) { }

I believe that GAE is processing the file, somehow, because when I select a file that is larger than the stated limit, $_POST is mucked and empty.  Also, when I select a large file, there is a significant time-delay in showing the called form, 'import_action.php.'

On other platforms, this just works.  What is the the config option I'm not setting?

Here's php.ini, which in GAE is a set of overrides:

```
output_buffering = on
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "phpversion, phpinfo"
track_vars = true
register_globals = true
enable_post_data_reading = true
file_uploads = on
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 30M
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is `upload_tmp_dir` set to something sensible in php.ini?

Comment: In my haste, I did not notice that when I select ascii files $_POST is populated, but when I select binary files $_POST is empty.  $_FILES is always empty.  This may be a clue that could lead me to what is wrong.

Comment: Good question!  I dumped phpinfo() - upload_tmp_fir = *no value*

Comment: ... that is upload_tmp_dir.  This begs the question whether I should just go ahead and try to set up a Google Cloud Storage 'bucket.'  The getting started tutorials don't say as much, but they suggest that any file manipulation requires a place to put them... and I have no blinking idea where an uploaded file would go on this server (uh, cloud.)  First, I'll try to assign a relative path statement in php.ini to upload_tmp_dir...

Comment: Hm. Trying to set upload_tmp_dir in php.ini (like: upload_tmp_dir = /tmp) does nothing - phpinfo() shows value unchanged from *no value*.  As I read the documentation further, I am suspicious that this cannot work without setting up an account that provides upload space for an application.  I have personal GCS space allocated, but I don't think it's associated with this application.

Comment: You could try setting upload_tmp_dir to php://temp/

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  I think my problems are even more basic: I am setting file_uploads = on in php.ini, but phpinfo() reports that value as 'off.'  Also, setting upload_tmp_dir in php.ini does nothing.  Clearly Google's php implementation is not letting me do basic stuff.  I'll have to dig in their documentation to find out how.  I wonder if anyone else out there is struggling with Google's implementation of php?

Comment: Found this Stack Exchange Post, which clearly addresses my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646338/turn-file-uploads-on-for-php-on-google-app-engine

Answer (score 0):

You should use `CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl()` for the form's 'action' attribute: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/#direct_uploads_to_google_cloud_storage_via_http_post