# Upload file and store in session or DB

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am aware that files which are uploaded to GAE must be stored in GCS -- however what about in the case where I wish to store the data in a BLOB or session for immediate handling and discarding?

Is it possible? Where do temp files get stored? Can I access the contents of the $_FILES global until the current request has timed out or completed???

Comment: It's not clear how upload to GCS changes anything here for you. Can you clarify?

Comment: Sure...when you upload a CSV file it usually gets uploaded to a temp path and then using PHP's move_uploaded_file() you permanently relocate the file and when the request finishes the temp file is no longer available (although I think it stays in the /var/tmp (C:/Windows/temp) for a time until a services cleans up files. In anycase, I simply need to know whether $_FILES variable is available on GAE so I can move the data into a BLOB instead of a file location.

Answer (score 1):

I'am not using PHP. In Python you can POST multi-part form data to your own handler, without using the blobstore or GCS. You can read the data (a temp StringIO object) in your handler.

This only works for small files! I see no reason this can also work in PHP.

Python example.py:

```
import webapp2
import mimetypes

class FileUpload(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):

        form = """
        <!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <title>File Upload</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="/file_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                <div><input type="file" name="file" /></div>
                <div><input type="submit" value="Upload"></div>
            </form>
        </body>
        </html>
        """

        self.response.headers[b'Content-Type'] = b'text/html'
        self.response.write(form)

    def post(self):

        file_upload = self.request.POST.get("file", None)
        name = file_upload.filename
        data = file_upload.file.read()

        self.response.headers[b'Content-Type'] = mimetypes.guess_type(name)[0]
        self.response.write(data)
```

Routing:  `webapp2.Route(r'/file_upload', handler='example.FileUpload')`

Answer (score 0):

BlobStore offers no advantages over GCS, and it's more expensive. Memcache can be lost at any moment.

I recommend that you upload a file to Google Cloud Storage. Next time when you need it, read it from GSC into a string, and store it in Memcache. The only reason to do it, of course, if you need this file frequently.

Comment: Its for an import CSV feature Idon't need to store the data any longer than a single request...then it's imported into my DB though...

Comment: You can read the details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646338/turn-file-uploads-on-for-php-on-google-app-engine